# redirect whole page to text/html in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an API which the output is text/html.
the vue make a request to this API and get the text/html data in a variable.
how can i build a page with those data and redirect whole page to that ? 
thanks alot.

Comment: I don't know why you need to redirect but if you have a vue page and want to parse html you can use the v-html directive. Eg. `<span v-html="rawHtml"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the v-html directive to interpret a string as html.

[Vue docs - Raw HTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Its look like this

```
<span v-html="someRawHtml"></span>
```